# PyGame Main Menu Bug

Tags: python, pygame

First of all sorry for my bad english. I want do a ping pong game with using pygame. I do these : singleplayer mode, doubleplayer mode, main menu and pause menu. I can enter pause menu while play game there is no trouble here. I can continue the game there is no trouble here too. But I can't go main menu. When i click Main Menu button i go doubleplayer mode.

If statement :

```
 if 462+225 > mouse[0] > 462 and 363+100 > mouse[1] > 363:
      pygame.draw.rect(display,(250,250,250), (462,363,225,100))

      mainmenutext=font.render("Main Menu", True, (0,0,0))
      mainmenutextRect=mainmenutext.get_rect()
      mainmenutextRect.center=(575, 410)
      display.blit(mainmenutext, mainmenutextRect)

      if click[0]==1
           mainmenu()
```

I am trying to return to the main menu with this code but it is not working
It is enter doubleplayer() function, I can't find bug.

Here is main menu function :

```
def mainmenu():
    while menu:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        display.fill((0,0,0))
        largefont=pygame.font.Font('data/BalooBhai-Regular.ttf',50)
        maintext=largefont.render("Ping Pong", True, (255,255,255))
        maintextRect=maintext.get_rect()
        maintextRect.center=(400,200)
        display.blit(maintext, maintextRect)

        #Button
        mainmenuoptionsfont=pygame.font.Font(None,30)

        pygame.draw.rect(display, (255,255,255), (100,350,250,125))
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (0,0,0), (112,363,225,100))

        singletext=mainmenuoptionsfont.render("Single Player", True, (255,255,255))
        singleRect=singletext.get_rect()
        singleRect.center=(225,410)
        display.blit(singletext, singleRect)


        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255), (450,350,250,125))
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(0,0,0), (462,363,225,100))

        dobuletext=mainmenuoptionsfont.render("Double Player", True, (255,255,255))
        doubletextRect=doubletext.get_rect()
        doubletextRect.center=(575, 410)
        display.blit(doubletext, doubletextRect)



        mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #print(mouse)
        click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        #print(click)



        if 112+225 > mouse[0] > 112 and 363+100 > mouse[1] > 363: #on hover
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (250,250,250), (100,350,250,125))

            singletext=mainmenuoptionsfont.render("Single Player", True, (0,0,0))
            singleRect=singletext.get_rect()
            singleRect.center=(225,410)
            display.blit(singletext, singleRect)

            if click[0]==1: #if click
                singleplayer()


        if 462+225 > mouse[0] > 462 and 363+100 > mouse[1] > 363: #on hover

            pygame.draw.rect(pencere,(250,250,250), (462,363,225,100))

            doubletext=mainmenuoptionsfont.render("Double Player", True, (0,0,0))
            doubletextRect=doubletext.get_rect()
            doubletextRect.center=(575, 410)
            display.blit(doubletext, doubletextRect)

            if click[0]==1: #if click
                doubleplayer()






        pygame.display.update()
```

Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you are handling this a bit unnecessary complicated. The way I do menu buttons is something like this:

1. Create the button texts and then create a rectangle around it (visible or non visible, doens't matter). This is easiest done by using `self.button1 = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, w)`.
2. Blit the buttons and texts on the screen.
3. In the event loop I then check for event clicks, like this:

   ```
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

           if self.button1.collidepoint(pos):
               print('Do what the button is supposed to do')
   ```

You are also duplicating a lot of code. Create a function that handles the text/button like below. The atttribute "boxed" is there to give an option to create a visible rectangle around the text.

```
    def create_button(self, text, font, color, x, y, boxed):
        text = font.render(text, True, color)
        rect = text.get_rect()
        rect.center = (x, y)
        if boxed:
            box = (rect[0] - PADDING, rect[1] - PADDING/2, rect[2] + PADDING*2, rect[3] + PADDING)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.win, WHITE, box, int(PADDING/2))
        self.win.blit(text, rect)

        return rect
```

Then you simply create the buttons with the following code:

```
self.button1 = self.create_button('Text 1', FONT, COLOR, X-COORDINATE, Y-COORDINATE, True)
self.button2 = self.create_button('Text 2', FONT, COLOR, X-COORDINATE, Y-COORDINATE, True)
```